# Ayuda con fallo en un adapter de un recyclerview, al meter varios items

Tags: java, android

y gracias de antemano. Os enseño mi codigo a ver si me podeis decir cual es mi error...

```
public class AdapterHome extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    Context context;

    public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View view;

        public TextView invoquer;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView icon;
        public ImageView champ1;
        public ImageView champ2;
        public ImageView champ3;
        public ImageView champ4;
        public ImageView champ5;



        public ViewHolder1(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            this.view = v;
            invoquer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.invoquer);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            champ1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ1);
            champ2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ2);
            champ3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ3);
            champ4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ4);
            champ5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ5);

        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View view;

        public TextView invoquer;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView icon;
        public ImageView champ1;
        public ImageView champ2;
        public ImageView champ3;
        public ImageView champ4;



        public ViewHolder2(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            this.view = v;
            invoquer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.invoquer);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            champ1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ1);
            champ2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ2);
            champ3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ3);
            champ4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.champ4);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        Log.e("LOLSTRATEGIIIII", "*****************************************************************  "+items.get(position).getItemType());
        return items.get(position).getItemType();
    }

    public AdapterHome(ArrayList<Item> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;

        switch(viewType)
        {
            case 1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.strategy_item,parent,false);
                context = v.getContext();
                viewHolder =  new ViewHolder1(v);
                break;
            case 2:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.combo_item,parent,false);
                context = v.getContext();
                viewHolder =  new ViewHolder2(v);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        String url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/";
        String imgUrl = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.1.1/img/profileicon/1145.png";
        String urlCham = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.10.1/img/champion/";

        Log.e("LOLSTRATEGIIIII", "*****************************************************************  "+holder.getItemViewType());

        switch(holder.getItemViewType())
        {
            case 1:
                Picasso.with(context).load(url+items.get(position).getChampions().get(0)).into(((ViewHolder1)holder).champ1);
                Picasso.with(context).load(url+items.get(position).getChampions().get(1)).into(((ViewHolder1)holder).champ2);
                Picasso.with(context).load(url+items.get(position).getChampions().get(2)).into(((ViewHolder1)holder).champ3);
                Picasso.with(context).load(url+items.get(position).getChampions().get(3)).into(((ViewHolder1)holder).champ4);
                Picasso.with(context).load(url+items.get(position).getChampions().get(4)).into(((ViewHolder1)holder).champ5);
                Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(((ViewHolder1)holder).icon);
                ((ViewHolder1)holder).name.setText(items.get(position).getName());
                ((ViewHolder1)holder).text.setText(items.get(position).getText());
                ((ViewHolder1)holder).invoquer.setText(items.get(position).getInvoquer());
            case 2:
                Picasso.with(context).load(urlCham+items.get(position).getChampions().get(0)).into(((ViewHolder2)holder).champ1);
                Picasso.with(context).load(urlCham+items.get(position).getChampions().get(1)).into(((ViewHolder2)holder).champ2);
                Picasso.with(context).load(urlCham+items.get(position).getChampions().get(2)).into(((ViewHolder2)holder).champ3);
                Picasso.with(context).load(urlCham+items.get(position).getChampions().get(3)).into(((ViewHolder2)holder).champ4);
                Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(((ViewHolder2)holder).icon);
                ((ViewHolder2)holder).name.setText(items.get(position).getName());
                ((ViewHolder2)holder).text.setText(items.get(position).getText());
                ((ViewHolder2)holder).invoquer.setText(items.get(position).getInvoquer());
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

El error que me da, es que no puedo hacer un casting de ViewHolder1 a ViewHolder2, y yo lo que intento es hacerlo del generico RecyclerView.ViewHolder a ViewHolder2 (Esto ocurre en el onBindViewHolder()).

---

La cosa es precisamente que no consigo entender por que tiene una referencia holder a ViewHolder1 si le estoy diciendo que solo intente castear a ViewHolder2 cuando el typo de item es 2...

Answer (score 0):

`ViewHolder1` y `ViewHolder2` no estan relacionados entre si por lo que no puedes efectuar el casting. Lo que si puedes hacer es castear ambos ViewHolders a `ViewHolder` pero no entre ellos.

Lo mas probable es que al momento de castar el objeto `holder` a `ViewHolder2`, en realidad `holder` contenga una referencia de `ViewHolder1` y de ahi el error. Tienes que confirmar que sea del tipo `ViewHolder2` para poder afectuar el casting.